# ATWINC1500 SSL socket connect aborted

Tags: sockets, wifi, tls1.2, microchip, mplab

I am currently working with **ATWINC1500** wifi network module on their WiFi click7 board which communicate with PIC32 (FreeRTOS Curiosity PIC32MZ EF).
I'm trying to create **tls** client example (TLS 1.2) using MPLAB Harmony v3. Socket has been opened successfully, I got the hostname and its IP address, but when I call the connect API, I got the SOCKET_MSG_CONNECT callback with error code (**connect aborted**). it's related to the certificate??

1. How installing the **root certificate** of my server in ATWINC1500 using **MPLAB harmony v3**.
2. How I can verify that my certificate has been installed
3. In Harmony 3, I need the setting of cipher suites or they are enabled by default, because I found this API (WDRV_WINC_SSLActiveCipherSuitesSet) but it's not used.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you but our subcontractor told us we couldn't use harmony V3 with Wifi that's why we had to move back to harmony v2

Comment: Thanks for replying @A.Gerber,
I could install root certificate to ATWINC1500's flash using scripts under Harmony 3 folder:  Harmony3\wireless\utilities\wifi\winc. After that, client could connect to the server successfully.